# executing multiple commands with find -exec but one of the command is 'cd'

Tags: bash, find

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

```
find .. -type d -depth 1 \( -exec cd "{}" \; -exec touch abc \; \)
```

I find that the 'cd' part of the command is not working, I get the file 'abc' in the current folder and not in the children folders

how can I execute the command inside the folders found?

To clarify, following Dibery's comment: I need to be able to cd to each folder to execute more complex commands (touch was  an example)

I'm on MacOS if it makes a difference

Comment: Will `-exec touch {}/abc \;` work?

Comment: no because touch is just in my example; I need to set the context to that folder to execute git commands

Comment: Um, maybe you can edit your question so that we can give a more accurate answer.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: is `find ..` a typo, or do you really want to search starting from the parent directory of the current directory?

Comment: it's not a typo: it's to be able to update git submodules in all sibling directories, so I need to be able to navigate them all and then execute my commands there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `cd` cannot be used with `-exec` in `find` because `cd` is a shell built-in (you can check this with `type cd`) rather than an executable (i.e., there's no such executable `/usr/bin/cd`). In your case, you may corporate the folder name into the `touch` command as:

```sh
find .. -type d -depth 1 -exec touch "{}/abc" \;
```

Or using `git` as you requested (the `-C` option allows you to run `git` as if you were in that directory):

```sh
find .. -type d -depth 1 -exec git -C "{}" some_git_action \;
```

Even without `find`:

```sh
for i in ../*/; do cd "$i"; some_cmd; cd -; done
```

`cd` to that directory and use `cd -` to go back to the original position, and adding the trailing `/` will make the asterisk expand to only the directories.

Answer (score 1):

If diberys' comment isn't sufficient, you can pipe the find to a while loop as such:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read -r dir; do
    cd $dir
    touch some_file.txt
    cd -
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shell loop and run your commands in a subshell so you don't have to change directory back again:

```
for d in ./*/; do (
    cd "$d"
    touch foo  # Or whatever you want
)
done
```

Alternatively, to get your `find` command to work, you could start a subshell for each directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c 'cd "$1"; touch bar' _ {} \;
```

Where again, `touch bar` can be something arbitrarily complex.